# Is it possible to use inheritance for classes inside media queries?

Tags: inheritance, less, media-queries

Lets say I have this:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .font-size-xxl {
        font-size: 48px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .font-size-xxl {
        font-size: 32px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .font-size-xxl {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}
```

...and I want multiple elements to inherit these rules. I tried using less inheritance:

```
h1 {
    .font-size-xxl;
}
```

...but it just doesn't work. First of all, it doesn't find the classes. It does if I take them out of the media queries but the media queries overrides don't apply.

Is what I'm trying to achieve doable? If so, what am I missing?

In case it matters, I'm using grunt-contrib-less 1.4.0.

Comment: No, if you want to inherit `.font-size-xxl` at global scope you need to have it there and thus put the media quieries inside. [For example](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/102bdc26b8e58e14bcd0895b8854ad00) (also use `extend` for trivial property cloning).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [extend](http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature).

```
h1:extend(.font-size-xxl) {

}
```

or

```
h1 {
  &:extend(.font-size-xxl)
}
```

Comment: As for why your current method isn't working, it seems it only copies the CSS of the class with the same scope (adding a .font-size-xxl class outside media queries would have been used, or doing the same thing inside each media query would have worked). I can't find anything to confirm this though.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you, @ColbySargent.